# Fedora 14 problem with using root

Tags: linux, root, fedora-14

I reinstalled my Linux and set the root password. But now I can't login to root. I can only run updates by password setted and do similar task but sudo is not working.

What's the problem?

Comment: What does sudo tell you when you try and use it?

Comment: that I'm not sudoer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora does not configure `sudo` by default.  Instead the default behavior is to obtain a root shell with the `su` command.  The rough equivalent to `sudo` is to use the `-c` argument to make it run a command.  For instance, to update your system you'd run:

```
su -c 'yum update'
```

As *Matt Jenkins* indicated, you can configure `sudo` to work on Fedora.  Follow his instructions for discovering the syntax of the  `sudoers` file and then run this command to edit it:

```
su -c visudo
```

To add yourself to the `admin` group more easily, without modifying `/etc/groups` directly, just run this command:

```
su -c 'usermod -aG admin [username]'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by one of two things:

1. You are not in the correct group to use `sudo`
2. You have not got the `sudo` configuration file set up right.

type:

```
$ man sudoers
```

and read all about setting up the sudoers file.

Editing of the sudoers file is done through `visudo`.

I have in my sudoers file:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and I am a member of the `admin` group (in /etc/group).  This lets me sudo to root without having to enter a password.

Comment: Hey! I can't perform this cause I can't use sudo or login to root, but I know root's password (which is only working on upgrades etc)

Comment: So boot into single user mode then.

Comment: HOW? I can't get to GRUB pressing shift all booting long

Comment: Then the final option - boot of a linux cd, mount the root filesystem, and edit the files you need to edit.